# Multiple Nginx Alias to One Location

Tags: regex, nginx, alias

I would like to create a location rule for two alias to one location.

This is the rule used for one location:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ { alias /var/www2/images/$1; }
```

What I would like to do is define two alias in location. So for example,
I can visit http://domain.com/styles/file.css and http://domain.com/css/file.css
and it would go to one alias which is /var/www2/styles/

I've tried something like this, but it did not work for me.

```
location ~ ^/(styles|css)(.*)$ { alias /var/www2/styles/$1; }
```

But the again, I don't know regex much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
location ~ ^/(?:styles|css)/(.*)$ { alias /var/www2/styles/$1; }
```

Or

```
location ~ ^/(styles|css)/(.*)$ { alias /var/www2/styles/$2; }
```

`$1` refers to the first capturing group `(...)`. When you added another group it referred to that one instead. You can use a non-capturing group `(?:...)` instead, or refer to the second capturing group `$2`.

Comment: Now I know this is a bit overkill, but how would I also allow only css file extension in this location and nothing else even if there is other files in my /styles/ folder ? Never mind got it.  location ~ ^/(?:styles|css)/(.*\.css)$

Comment: This of course works only with one extension, how would I add more then one ?

Comment: I got it with  location ~ ^/(?:icons|ico)/(.*\.(png|gif|ico))$ {  If you know a better way please reply.

Comment: @Tux, that looks fine. Altho you can use a non-capturing group instead of the capturing one: `^/(?:icons|ico)/(.*\.(?:png|gif|ico))$`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for a regex that matches paths starting with a string instead of ending with a string, here's a working example that matches `/users`, `/sales` and `/invoices` (as well as subpaths like `/users/settings`):

```
location ~ ^\/(users|sales|invoices) {
     proxy_pass         http://sample.local; 
}
```